# Write into cells VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I want to iterate through all pages in a workbook and then write into all those cells. I am trying to say that given the cell I am currently write to that specific cell, in a specific worksheet. How can I go about doing it so that is the cell="foo" that "this worked" is written into that same cell code, but in a new worksheet.

```
  Sub WorksheetLoop()

     Dim ws As Worksheets beginning
     Dim starting_ws As Worksheet
     Set starting_ws = ActiveSheet 
     ws_num = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
     For I = 1 To ws_num
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(I).Activate
        For Each Cell In Range("G9:G39").Cells
           If Cell = "foo" Then
           Sheets("mysheet").Cell.Value = "this worked"
           Cell = "this worked"
           Exit For

        Next

     Next


  End Sub
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're actually trying to do.  [Before others can help, a clear question must be formulated](http://idownvotedbecau.se/unclearquestion)

Comment: Each `Cell` contains the address of a specific cell in a specific worksheet in a specific workbook. You can use the same `Cell` object to write to two different worksheets.

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

```
Sub WorksheetLoop()
     ws_num = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
     For I = 1 To ws_num
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(I).Activate
        Range("G9:G39").Value = "this worked"
     Next
  End Sub
```

You don't need to loop over the individual cell in the worksheets and you also don't need the `Activate`:

```
Sub WorksheetLoop2()
     ws_num = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
     For I = 1 To ws_num
        With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(I)
            .Range("G9:G39").Value = "this worked"
        End With
     Next
  End Sub
```

Comment: @barskyn  If this Answer is of no value, I will delete it.

Comment: Typo: You mean `.Range("G9:G39").Value = "this worked"`. Notice the `.` before `Range()` or else it scopes to `ActiveWorksheet`.

Comment: @ja72  **You are correct!**  I will fix ..................... **THANKS!**

Comment: That dot makes a big difference in this case. PS. Try to test code before posting. It would help you and the community in the future.

Comment: @ja72  I agree with you completely.

Answer (score 0):

you may be after this:

```
Sub WorksheetLoop()
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Dim cell As Range

    For Each sht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets ' loop through sheets
        If sht.Name <> "mysheet" Then ' avoid considering "mysheet" sheet
            For Each cell In sht.Range("G9:G39") ' loop through current sheet range "G9:G39"
                If cell.Value = "foo" Then Sheets("mysheet").Range(cell.Address).Value = "this worked" ' if current cell value is "foo" then write "This worked" in corresponding cell of "mysheet" sheet
            Next
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the worksheet which the range object refers to. For convenience store the top-left range of each working range also.

```
Sub WorksheetLoop()
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, ws_num As Long
    ws_num = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count

    Dim ws As Worksheet, rng As Range
    Dim my_ws As Worksheet, my_rng As Range
    Set my_ws = Sheets("mysheet")
    Set my_rng = my_ws.Range("G9")

    For i = 1 To ws_num
        Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(i)
        Set rng = ws.Range("G9")
        ' Go down 30 cells from G9
        For j = 1 To 30
            If rng.Cells(j, 1).Value = "foo" Then
                my_rng.Cells(j, 1).Value = "this worked"
                rng.Cells(j, 1).Value = "this worked"
            End If
        Next j
    Next
End Sub
```

**Caution** what happens when `ws` points to `Sheet("mysheet")`?